# chrome-extension: How to detect and retrieve url from tab when redirect happens?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Just started on chrome - extension development. I'm trying to retrieve the url from a newly created tab but my expected url comes from the server as response with 302 status code and browser redirects to it. I tried with chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener() but its not detecting the URL with 302. I searched in chrome.tabs API and i don't see any events for redirect. What is the best way to detect if any redirection is happening in the tab and get the url from that object?

My use case is, when user clicks on one button, it opens a new tab with a specific url and since this url is SSO protected which will go through SSO dance and finally goes to target page.During SSO dance there are 3 redirects happening before serving the target page and i'm trying to detect and retrieve one of the url in the redirect process.

P.S: This is my first question and i'm excited to be part of this community. Thanks in advance.

Update1: I tried with chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRedirect.addListener

**manifest.json**

```html
{
  "name": "CatBlock",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "I can't has cheezburger!",
  "permissions": ["alarms", "webRequest", "webRequestBlocking", "activeTab", "tabs",
                  "https://*/*"],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },

  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

**background.js**

```js
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  function(info) {
    console.log("Cat intercepteddd: " + info.url);
   
  });

chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRedirect.addListener(
    function(info) {
      console.log("Cat intercepteddd: " + info.url);
      
});

chrome.webRequest.onResponseStarted.addListener(
    function(info) {
      console.log("Cat intercepteddd: " + info.url);
    
});
```

Comment: See examples and documentation for chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRedirect

Comment: And the URL where you're having the problem is? Also, be specific as to which URL you are trying to detect.

Comment: @wOxxOm Actually, i did try that before posting it here but it didn't help me at all. May be i'm doing something wrong.. This what i have so far for detection...

Comment: manifest.json

{
  "name": "CatBlock",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "I can't has cheezburger!",
  "permissions": ["alarms", "webRequest", "webRequestBlocking", "activeTab", "tabs",
                  "https://*/*"],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },

  "manifest_version": 2
}

Comment: background.js
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  function(info) {
    alert("Cat intercepteddd: " + info.url);
    // Redirect the lolcal request to a random loldog URL.
  });

chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRedirect.addListener(
    function(info) {
      alert("Cat intercepteddd: " + info.url);
      // Redirect the lolcal request to a random loldog URL.
});

chrome.webRequest.onResponseStarted.addListener(
    function(info) {
      alert("Cat intercepteddd: " + info.url);
      // Redirect the lolcal request to a random loldog URL.
});

Comment: This code is unreadable, don't you think? Also, don't use `alert`, use `console.log` which you can see in background page devtools.

Answer (score 0):

```
const responseListener = function(details) {
  const headers = details.responseHeaders;
  for (let i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
   if (headers[i].name == "location") {
    console.log("redirectURL:" + headers[i].value);
   }
  }
  return { responseHeaders: newHeaders};
};

chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(
responseListener,{urls: [URL_TO_DETECT]}, ["blocking", "responseHeaders"]);
```

Usually 303 redirects will be caught on the response headers, use the above code to get the redirect url from response header, make sure to have the code in background.js